# VS2015: Build errors when building app with Typescript 1.5 and Experimental Decorators

Tags: msbuild, typescript, visual-studio-2015, ecmascript-6, typescript1.5

I have looked high and low for the solution to this, and I have gotten close, but still having a little trouble.

The error:

```
Build: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Specify '--experimentalDecorators' to remove this warning.
```

This error appears for every usage of decorators. I have the MSBuild set up with

```
    <TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>True</TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>
    <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
```

and that removed half of the errors (compiler errors, not build errors). However, now I'm stuck with the build errors. The .ts files still get compiled to .js, no problem.*** But the exceptions get in the way of building the rest of the solution.

If any of this doesn't make sense, please let me know. I'm not the best with words.

**Edit**: I discovered that the .js is created upon save, not build. So anything relating to build is "broken."

Comment: `However, now I'm stuck with the build errors` Is the error message you are getting for these the same?

Comment: @basarat Yes. Originally each error would be duplicated, once by the compiler (like if you're missing a semi-colon) and once during the build process (these latter errors were all prefaced with Build: ). I got rid of the compiler errors by fixing the msbuild file and the csproj, but I'm still stuck with the Build: errors.

Comment: Have you added these options to both `Debug` and `Release` configurations?

Comment: Yeah, there are a few more configurations that I haven't already set up, but I assumed that that wouldn't be getting in the way as I haven't even switched to those configs yet. I updated them just now, however, and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I ended up modifying the *.csproj* to change all `TypeScriptCompile` elements to just plain `Content` elements, and I used my own compile task (via Gulp).

For example,
`<TypeScriptCompile Include="app.ts" />` became `<Content Include="app.ts" />`.

I also removed any imports that referenced Typescript related MSBuild targets, i.e. `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />`

I still get IDE (and Resharper, if you use that) support for Typescript - I just explicitly tell Visual Studio not to handle any TS compilation for my project. It seems that the only downside is having to manage my Gulp tasks for compiling the Typescript. Using Task Runner Explorer extension for VS, adding the Gulp compilation task as part of the project's build, or just using the Gulp task inside of a gulp watch can mitigate the tradeoff.

Comment: Does this also circumvent VS complaining about complex decorators? I've found that it's become very annoying to code TypeScript from within VS as the errors have gotten in the way, although I'd like to (I use it for the rest of my project, of course).

Comment: @POB VS will still highlight decorators red, but no compile error will ever be thrown. Agreed that it is annoying

Comment: That's what I thought. I've been using grunt to compile, but thanks for the tidbit about editing the csproj. I didn't really think about that!